# Ruby on Rails: Create a flat array of dates using start and end date ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, date

I want to get a flat array of dates in a date range for Items with many Bookings. A Booking has `:start_date` and `:end_date`.

example, Item has these bookings:

```
Booking A: 10/1/17 to 10/3/17
Booking B: 11/2/17 to 11/4/17
```

I tried using pluck. `Item.bookings.pluck[:start_date, :end_date]` and it gives me an array that looks like this `[["10,01,17", "10,03,17"], ["11,02,17" , "11,04,17" ]]`

What I need is a flat array with the date ranges like this `["10,01,17", "10/02/17", "10,03,17", "11,02,17" , "11,03,17", "11/04/17"]`

Comment: you need to have the dates between date X and date Y in your array?

Comment: (Date.today..Date.today+10.days).to_a

Comment: In my controller I'd like to write a query and pass to an instance variable. I can query Item.bookings.pluck(:start_date, :end_date) and that would give me an array of start and end dates. I need to first get the ranges including start and end date for each array then flatten the array so all the dates are just in one array as illustrated in the example. Thank you!

Comment: `Item.bookings.pluck[:start_date, :end_date].flatten` works?

Comment: Don't tell me you're using a string column to store dates?

Comment: not using a string... thought it would more readable to use those numbers in the example, I get something that looks like this: [["2017-10-17T00:00:00.000Z","2017-10-24T00:00:00.000Z"],["2017-11-22T00:00:00.000Z","2017-11-22T00:00:00.000Z"],["2017-11-22T00:00:00.000Z","2017-11-22T00:00:00.000Z"]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to get ranges, you need actual Date objects. To get those out of strings like yours, you'll need to use `Date.strptime`. Then you can build Ranges out of the date pairs, and then convert back to strings with `Date#strftime`:

```
require 'date'
format = '%m/%d/%y' # mm/dd/yy; adjust as needed
dates = Item.bookings.pluck(%i<start_date end_date>).map do |bounds|
  Range.new(*bounds.map { |d| Date.strptime(d, format) }).map do |d|
    d.strftime(format)
  end
end.flatten
```

Which with your example data set gives me this:

```
["10/01/17", "10/02/17", "10/03/17", "11/02/17", "11/03/17", "11/04/17"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get an error that reads: Unsupported argument type: Symbol. Construct an Arel node instead.

Comment: That sounds like `pluck` doesn't like the array of symbols as an argument? I thought that's what you were sending in your original code. The `pluck` call should look just like whatever worked for you; none of that has anything to do with my solution. None of the rest of it touches any Rails stuff; it's just pure Ruby.